# Set max-height on image transforms?

Tags: image-transforms

Is it possible to define an aspect ratio / set a max height on an image transform, without using a plugin?

Let's say the width is fixed to 600px, but the height can be any value up to 800px?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass an array instead of the image-transform handle to the `getUrl()` function

```
{% set transform = {
    'width' => 600,
    'height' => (asset.getWidth() <= 800)? asset.getWidth() : 800
} %}
{{ asset.getUrl(transform) }}
```